# HTTP request in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have only HTTP API for my SMS gateway for which I create an ASP.NET application to send SMS using ASP.NET page. The below string `url` is the HTTP API. Now, how to post this `url` in ASP.NET page to send SMS.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userk = "***********";
        string passk = "***********";
        string senderk = "someid";
        string phonek = "00000000000";
        string messagek = "This is a test API";
        string priorityk = "ndnd";
        string typek = "normal";
        string url = "http://indiansms.smsmaker.in/api/sendmsg.php?user=" + userk + "&pass=" + passk + "&sender=" + senderk + "&phone=" + phonek + "&text=" + messagek + "&priority=" + priorityk + "&stype=" + typek;
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate of [ASP.NET SMS Gateway API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294250/asp-net-sms-gateway-api), posted earlier by same user.

Comment: @Michael - Question is changed. Please reread the question. Also I just asked here how to post not to create an API for me. Moreover I didn't receive any relevant answer to my previous question.

Comment: You're trying to solve the same problem, just phrased differently. And "I didn't get a good answer" is not a reason to repost.

Comment: @Michael - I believe that SO users answering to this question is much easier than previous one as my previous question is incomplete. But if I edit my previous question due to timeout its getting back and nobody is looking at that question and that question will be left over as a question forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using either [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) or [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)? The fact that you're doing this from within an ASP.NET page is mostly irrelevant...

Note that you should escape URI parameters - otherwise you'll run into trouble with values such as a message of "hello & goodbye".

Comment: Thanks! this is working. but what do you mean by URI parameters?

Comment: @Kars: The username, message, priority etc - see Uri.EscapeUriString.

Comment: But what's the alternative? if I remove `&` how HTTP API differentiates values?

Comment: @Kars: You don't remove `&` - you use it as a delimiter, but escape it *within* values (along with other characters).

Comment: do you mean `"&" + "pass" + passk "` for `"&pass=" + passk`

Comment: @Kars: No, I mean something like `"&pass=" + Uri.EscapeUriString(passk)` - but BrokenGlass's `UploadValues` call is a better bet, IMO.

Comment: Thanks a lot.! I will do it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`WebClient.UploadValues()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `HttpWebRequest` with preset data

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://myurl");
        request.Method = "POST";
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```